# Connection computers on network

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, port

I am working on a communication medium between two computers. They are both on the same network. I know the remote ip of each device.

I am trying to write a C program that acts as a server on one machine, and a client on the other.

I am trying to make this connection using TCP protocol on port 311 from the client. I am wondering how to setup the server? Which address do I bind to on the server so it will accept remote request from a client service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you bind to the special ip address called INADDR_ANY.  This allows your server to be available to incoming connections on any interface.  This way you can connect to your server via localhost/loopback if you're on the same machine or via any of the external interfaces the server computer may have - regardless of the configuration.

Here's a good [description](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F01.full/www/assignments/P2/htmlsim_split/node18.html)

Comment: No, not any PORT, any IP address.  You still have to provide a single port to bind your socket to when you call [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind).  In order to listen on more than one PORT, you have to have a socket per port. -- This was in response to a question asking if it would accept connections on any port.

Comment: okay thanks, also I don't know where my previous comment went. In any case, this does answer my question. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  I edited my comment with the context of your comment questions.

Comment: Also, an "interface" is a "network card".  However, sometimes the network card is virtual (such as loopback) or a single card with multiple NICs (network interface controller) on a single card.  Each NIC (real or virtual) will have an IP address.  INADDR_ANY lets you accept on any of those IP addresses.

Comment: oh okay, great, your experience of networking is a great help :)

Comment: Doesn't every tutorial on writing network servers show how to do this?

Comment: @Barmar shhhh.  If everyone followed the tutorials, there would be no reputation for the rest of us :)